# Python 3.7- PhantomJS - Driver.get(url) with 'Window handle/name is invalid or closed?'

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, phantomjs, python-3.7

Using two functions to scrape a website results in a driver.get error.

I've tried different variations of while and for loops to get this to work.  Now I get a driver.get error.  The initial function works on its own, but when running both functions one after another I get this error.

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4, time
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = 'C:\\PhantomJS\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
jobtit = 'some+job'
location = 'some+city'
urlpag = ('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=' + jobtit + '&l=' + location + '%2C+CA')



def initial_scrape():
    data = []
    try:
        driver.get(urlpag)
        results = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
        print('Finding the results for the first page of the search.')
        for result in results: # loop 2
            job_name = result.text
            link = result.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
            job_link = link.get_attribute('href')
            data.append({'Job' : job_name, 'link' : job_link})
            print('Appending the first page results to the data table.')
            if result == len(results):
                return
    except Exception:
        print('An error has occurred when trying to run this script.  Please see the attached error message and screenshot.')
        driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
        driver.close()
    return data


def second_scrape():
    data = []
    try:
        #driver.get(urlpag)
        pages = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pagination')
        print('Variable nxt_pg is ' + str(nxt_pg))
        for page in pages:
            page_ = page.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
            page_link = page_.get_attribute('href')
            print('Taking a look at the different page links..')
            for page_link in range(1,pg_amount,1):
                driver.click(page_link)
                items = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
                print('Going through each new page and getting the jobs for ya...')
                for item in items:
                    job_name = item.text
                    link = item.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
                    job_link = link.get_attribute('href')
                    data.append({'Job' : job_name, 'link' : job_link})
                    print('Appending the jobs to the data table....')
                if page_link == pg_amount:
                    print('Oh boy! pg_link == pg_amount...time to exit the loops')
                    return
    except Exception:
        print('An error has occurred when trying to run this script.  Please see the attached error message and screenshot.')
        driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
        driver.close()
    return data
```

Expected:

Initial Function

1. Get website from urlpag
2. Find element by tag name and loop through elements while appending to a list.
3. When done will all elements exit and return the list.

Second Function

1. While still on urlpag, find element by class name and get the links for the next pages to scrape.
2. As we have each page to scrape, go through each page scraping and appending the elements to a different table.
3. Once we reach our pg_amount limit - exit and return the finalized list.

Actual:

Initial Function

1. Get website from urlpag
2. Find element by tag name and loop through elements while appending to a list.
3. When done will all elements exit and return the list.

Second Function

1. Finds class pagination, prints nxt_variable and then throws the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\Indeedscraper\indeedscrape.py", line 23, in initial_scrape
    driver.get(urlpag)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Currently Window handle/name is invalid (closed?)"
```

Comment: @QHarr That was an error when pasting the code here.  The two variables are located before urlpag in the actual script and here now(since i;ve updated). Thanks

Comment: FYI, PhantomJS is no longer supported.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev Noted.  Not sure how this helps me with my original question

Comment: It's gentle reminder to consider migrating to another Web driver product, like maybe Puppeteer, rather than fight with PhantomJS. If it turns out the issue is with PhantomJS itself, there is no chance of a vendor fix.

Answer (score 1):

For individuals having this error, I ended up switching to chromedriver and using that instead for webscraping.  It appears that using the PhantomJS driver will sometimes return this error.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, until I placed my `driver.close()` *after* I was done interacting with selenium objects. I ended up closing the driver at the end of my script just to be on the safe side.